# How do I access members of elements in a struct array in c#

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a structure array **Entry[2]**, and its layout in memory looks like this: **[hashcode(4byte),next(4byte),hashcode(4byte),next(4byte)]**

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8, Pack = 1)]
    struct Entry
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int hashCode;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public int next;
    }
```

So now I'm going to access this **Entry[0].next** in my code

```
class Test
    {
        Entry[] entries = new Entry[2];

        void AccessElement()
        {
            int n = entries[0].next; 
        }
    }
```

So in the AccessElement method, I only have one line of code, which is: **entries[0].next**, and I want to know how does the CLR help us access this  element.
I have two ideas in my mind right now,I'm going to give you the pseudocode.
**1).idea 1**
`int n = (&entries+0)->next`
  Fetches the address of the entries object, takes the first element (offset 0), and accesses the value of the member next (4byte relative to the base address of the element).

**2).idea 2**

```
Entry entry = Copy(&entries[0],8);
int n = entry.next;
```

Copies the first element of the entries object (offset 0) into the current stack and returns the **next** member of the current stack object **entry**

These two ideas are my thoughts on CLR access to the members of elements in the structure array, which is related to whether I use struct in some cases, after all, a large amount of data mov has some overhead.So can someone tell me the true pattern of how the CLR accesses members of elements in a struct array?Is there any difference between debug and release?

thank you

---

This is a sink code. Can someone read it for me

```
                   Entry[] entries = new Entry[2];
        00007FFB4B6D47F0 mov         rcx,7FFB4B96361Ah
        00007FFB4B6D47FA mov         edx,2
        00007FFB4B6D47FF call        00007FFBAA902630
        00007FFB4B6D4804 mov         qword ptr[rbp + 20h], rax
        00007FFB4B6D4808 mov         rax,qword ptr[rbp + 20h]
        00007FFB4B6D480C mov         qword ptr[rbp + 30h], rax
                    int n = entries[1].next;
        00007FFB4B6D4810 mov         rax,qword ptr[rbp + 30h]
        00007FFB4B6D4814 mov         edx,1
        00007FFB4B6D4819 cmp         rdx,qword ptr[rax + 8]
        00007FFB4B6D481D jb          00007FFB4B6D4824
        00007FFB4B6D481F call        00007FFBAADA2660
        00007FFB4B6D4824 lea         rax,[rax+rdx*8+10h]  
        00007FFB4B6D4829 mov         eax,dword ptr[rax + 4]  
        00007FFB4B6D482C mov         dword ptr[rbp + 2Ch], eax
```

Maybe I think too much?I just looked at the IL code:
This is IL when Entry is of type reference

```
        // Entry1[] entries = new Entry1[2];
        IL_0001 ldc.i4.2
        IL_0002 newarr      ConsoleApp9.Entry1
        IL_0007 stloc.0
        // int n = entries[1].next;
        IL_0008 ldloc.0
        IL_0009 ldc.i4.1
        IL_000A ldelem.ref
        IL_000B ldfld       System.Int32 ConsoleApp9.Entry1::next
        IL_0010 stloc.1
```

This is IL if Entry is of type structure

```
    // Entry[] entries = new Entry[2];
    IL_0001 ldc.i4.2
    IL_0002 newarr    ConsoleApp9.Entry
    IL_0007 stloc.0
    // int n = entries[1].next;
    IL_0008 ldloc.0
    IL_0009 ldc.i4.1
    IL_000A ldelema   ConsoleApp9.Entry
    IL_000F ldfld System.Int32 ConsoleApp9.Entry::next
    IL_0014 stloc.1
```

For a structured array, the instruction is ldelema ：Loads the address of the array element at a specified array index onto the top of the evaluation stack as type & (managed pointer).

For a reference array, the instruction is ldelem.ref ：Loads the element containing an object reference at a specified array index onto the top of the evaluation stack as type O (object reference).

So the truth is out?

Comment: You can inestigate this yourself: compile the code and have a look at the generated IL (e.g. using ildasm).

Comment: @KlausGütter indeed OP should look themselves. Just  not at IL. They need to look at JIT'ed code in retail build for what they are asking. It is not necessary for IL to match assembly level instructions as pretty much all optimizations happen via JIT and not during compilation.

Comment: Definitely the elements of an array aren't being copied to any local variable when accessed. There is no need to do that as an array is continuous block of memory underneath so its elements can be accessed by offset on instruction level, while copying would impose serious performance impact depending on size of array and size of its elements.

Comment: As per disassembled code: *1)* `lea rax,[rax+rdx*8+10h]`- loads address of array element with index `1` (1 is loaded into `edx` which is lower part of `rdx`, `rax` contains address of array instance, 10h is length of CLR instance header on a x64 system) into `rax` register, *2)* `mov eax,dword ptr[rax + 4]` - moves value of `next` field of the element with index `1` (addressed by `rax`) into `eax` register and *3)* `mov dword ptr[rbp + 2Ch], eax` stores this value in the local variable addressed somewhere on stack. So as you can see no copying of entire array element happens.